# Submit POST method not calling PHP code

Tags: php

I'm trying to get my submit POST methode working. If i put in my username and password, the button does not let me see the echo i should see. It doesn't show anything at all. I also tried to put an echo after my submit post, nothing happend and i could not see what went wrong before that. I used some websites to try and get out it by myself. I hope you guys can help me !

php:

```
 <?php 
// validate the form for loggin the user 
//Function Login(){


//server info
$server = 'Localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'CMS';

//connect to database
$mysqli = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db);

//show errors 
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);
//}

session_start();
//login();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$username = ($_POST['uname']);
$password = ($_POST['psw']);
$query = "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username='$username' 
AND password='$password'";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if( $num_row ==1 )
   {
        $_SESSION['userid']=$row['userid'];
        echo 'hi there';
        exit;
   }

else
   {
        echo 'oops can not do that';
   }

}
?>
```

html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="Text" placeholder ="Enter Username" name="uname" required> <br />
<input type ="Password" placeholder ="Enter Password" name="psw" required> <br />
<button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

*All this code is in one document*

Comment: You don't have a name in your submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have   a null action in your code   (`action =""`)
in action you should assingn the url for you php code file

```
<form action="/your_path/your_php_file.php" method="post">
    <input type="Text" placeholder ="Enter Username" name="uname" required> <br />
    <input type ="Password" placeholder ="Enter Password" name="psw" required> <br />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

or if in all in one .php document

remove the `action = ""`

```
<form  method="post">
    <input type="Text" placeholder ="Enter Username" name="uname" required> <br />
    <input type ="Password" placeholder ="Enter Password" name="psw" required> <br />
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```